# Trigonometry algorithm to detect the hour position on an analog clock

Tags: ios, swift, algorithm, math, trigonometry

I have a view in my app in the size of 312x312 that contains an analog clock like this:

[image: Clock]

I have a method that gets called every time the user taps on the clock.

I'm trying to use trigonometry to determinate in what hour (clock section) the user tapped, like this:

```
let touchPoint = tapGestureRecognizer.locationInView(self)

let delta = CGPoint(x: center.x - touchPoint.x, y: center.y - touchPoint.y)
let distance = hypotf(Float(delta.x), Float(delta.y))
//Ignore points outside circle
guard distance < Float(min (frame.width / 2, frame.height / 2)) else {
    return
}
let angle = atan2f(Float(delta.y), Float(delta.x))
let proportion = angle / (Float(M_PI) * 2) + 0.5
let hour = (Int(proportion * 12) + 3) % 12 + 1
print (hour)
```

but it gives me the wrong results:

In format of `hourTapped: hourPrinted`:

- 12:12
- 1:1
- 2:1
- 3:1
- 4:2
- 5:1
- 6:11
- 7:11
- 8:11
- 9:11
- 10:12
- 11:12

and sometimes i's even ignores taps that are inside the circle.

What's wrong with this method?

Thank you!

Comment: Is this image in an image view? Does the image fill the image view exactly? In the posted code, if `self` the image view?

Comment: @rmaddy ye, the image is an UIImageView, and yes, it fills the image exactly. And no, self is a custom UIView that has the UIImageView as a subview

Comment: Then change `self` to a reference to the image view. You want the touch point to be relative to the image view. And references to `self.center` need to be changed to the image view's `center`.

Comment: Have you considered negative angles?

Comment: @rmaddy Great! Thanks!!